# Странные символы в выводе в программе на Си

Tags: c, вывод, символы

Всем доброго времени суток. Вопрос к знатокам СИ. Имеется вот такая корявая функция для изъятия из строки лишь уникальных символов. Программа правильно определяет символы но на выходе в получаемой строке появляются какие-то странные каракули. Скрин результата смотрите ниже кода.
P.S. Буду рад любой критике кода.

```
void unique_symbol(char* str)
{
   if (str == NULL) return;

   int size_str = strlen(str);
   char* result = malloc(sizeof(char) * size_str);
   char sym;

   for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < size_str; i++) {

      sym = str[i];

      if (strchr(result, sym) == NULL) {
        result = strcat(result, &sym);
      }
  }
  result[size_str+1] = '\0';

  FILE* fp = fopen("./first", "w");
  fprintf(fp, "%s\n", result);
}
```

[image: вывод программы]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первая проблема происходит при вызове [**strcat**(3)](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=strcat&category=3&russian=0). Во втором аргументе она ожидет получить строку, завершающуюся нулевым байтом. У вас это не так, вы передаёте адрес только единичного символа, за которым следуют какие-то другие данные, где может не быть нуля (кажется, там уже идёт адрес возврата).

Вторая проблема наблюдается при попытке записи `'\0'` сразу после окончания цикла. Запись происходит за пределы выделенной области памяти. Вы выделили только size_str байт, на которые указывает result, а пытаетесь записать в ячейку `result[size_str + 1]`. Максимальный индекс, в который можно что-то ещё безопасно писать равен (size_str - 1).

Теперь по поводу алгоритма. Есть подозрения, что функия [**strcat**(3)](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=strcat&category=3&russian=0) вам не понадобится. Записывайте в результат текущий символ самостоятельно. Как-то так:

```
result[j++] = sym;
```

Обратите внимание, увеличение индекса для результата происходит не на каждой итерации цикла. После окончания цикла ноль надо записывать как-то так:

```
result[j] = '\0';
```

Переменную j нужно будет ещё использовать за пределами тела цикла, поэтому её стоит объявить вне этого цикла. Увеличение j тут уже не будет играть роли.

Comment: Да, действительно, вроде изначально было проще сделать без strcat(), я фиг знает что меня побудило на её использование. Сейчас перепилил как вы посоветовали, и вроде всё работает корректно. Правда пока не разобрался с комментарием по поводу рекомендации к применению функции memset(), пойду штудировать документацию.

Comment: Это просто везение :) Смотрите, выделяется память `result`, но не обнуляете ее. Далее при поиске `strchr(result, sym)` - **где остановится этот поиск**, при том, что вы просто добавляете по символу, не добавляя завершающий ноль? А если так повезет, что мусор в памяти будет строкой со всеми символами от 1 до 255?

Comment: @Harry, я понимаю, что на практике лучше юзать Вашу функцию. Там нет никакого лишнего и бессмысленного выделения памяти для новой строки и всё такое. Но мне так, лишь, для личностного роста. Если я после malloc() функции добавлю:
memset(result, 0, (sizeof(char) * size_str));
Станет ли тот код чуть более стабильным и устойчивым?

Comment: Да, станет. Или используйте не `malloc`, а `calloc` - он обнуляет выделенную память.

Answer (score 2):

Извините уж, но у вас такого наверчено, что проще написать с нуля...
Вобщем, [вот](https://ideone.com/rKDVqm) (заниматься O(n) не стал, раз уж у вас все равно O(n^2), сделал O(n^2) для простоты):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * unique_symbol(char * s)
{
    if (s == NULL) return s;
    int i = 1, j = 1;
    for(;s[i];++i)
    {
        int found = 0;
        for(int k = 0; k < j; ++k)
            if (s[k] == s[i]) { found = 1; break; }
        if (!found) s[j++] = s[i];
    }
    s[j] = 0;
    return s;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char s[] = "wvsvsvmskx ksgyggfxa zn jakgsd caaakggzkas";
    printf("%s\n",unique_symbol(s));
}
```

Comment: Проверил, ваш алгоритм. Всё чётко работает. Надеюсь, я очень скоро до росту до его понимания.))
Спасибо за участие.

Comment: Там нет ничего сложного. Берем строку, текущий просматриваемый символ i, *записываемый* - j. Понятно, что первый символ всегда будет записан, так что начинаем с 1, а не с 0. Увеличиваем i, проверяем, нет ли уже этого символа в строке (до j-го символа! не далее - т.е. только в *новой* строке). Если нет - записываем его на j-е место, увеличиваем j. Если есть - ничего не делаем. Все это в рамках *одной строки*. Когда строка закончилась - пишем в j-ом месте нуль, чтоб завершить строку. Все.

Answer (score 1):

Помимо указанных выше ошибок, есть еще одна: выделенный буфер будет содержать мусор и strcat может работать совершенно непредсказуемо. Добавьте обнуление через memset() сразу после malloc.

Comment: Спасибо! Пошёл знакомиться с memset().